# Double text on Cufón using IE8

Tags: cufon

We've been having this very weird Cufón issue in IE which cause we haven't been able to adress. I think it's something to do with text that's hidden and cuffóned.

The problem is that both the cuffoned and normal text are shown (and I noticed that the tag  that is normally used by Cufón is replaced by <:cufon>). Anyway, this happens in native IE8 (not the "IE8 mode" of IE9).

A jsfiddle is worth more than a thousand words: http://jsfiddle.net/Osoascam/vqnh3/1/
To test, click on the red circle so that the text moves left 4 times (for some weird reason this only works on FF and IE, but it reproduces the IE8 error, so I can live with that).

Any help would be very appreciated. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Here is how it looks on IE8]

Comment: Looks like Cufon + jCarousel have issues, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160494/jcarousel-and-cufon-arent-co-operating-animation-makes-cufon-go-away, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842516/cufon-text-disappear-in-jcarousel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482181/jcarousel-cufon-disappears-after-the-first-rotation, and https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/207

Answer (score 2):

Check your js plugins, disable them one by one and see which one is causing the problem.

The same thing happened for me while using cufon 0.9 & modernizr 2.5.3, which includes html5shiv script, and this one breaks cufon.

Solved my problem replacing production version of html5shiv inside modernizr script with a release candidate(RC1) version of html5shiv from [github](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/tree/master/dist).

Good luck!

Comment: Well, the only plug in there is jCarousel, so it must be that.